# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING & FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION on PricebookEntry Insert

Tags: apex, exception, dmlexception, insert, pricebookentry

I want to use standard price for the Pricebook entry.

```
  PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id='01sN00000002OTsIAM',
        IsActive=true, 
        Product2Id='01tN0000004JGeuIAG', 
        UseStandardPrice=true
        );
    insert pbe;
```

I get this error.

> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [UnitPrice]:
>   [UnitPrice]

So, I changed to mention the List Price (which is the unitPrice). I still get the error!

```
PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id='01sN00000002OTsIAM',
    IsActive=true, 
    Product2Id='01tN0000004JGeuIAG', 
    UseStandardPrice=true,
    UnitPrice = 0.70
    );

insert pbe;
```

I get the following error

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception

**UPDATE**

I read that `UseStandardPrice==true` cannot be set. It has to be false. [help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193277&type=1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193277&type=1)

Setting it to False actually inserts the record. But I want it to be set to true.

Comment: Do pricebookentry already has value for the pricebook2id and product2id combination?

Comment: **No!  I did query for that - 0 results** 
(select id from pricebookentry where Pricebook2Id='01sN00000002OTsIAM' AND Product2Id='01tN0000004JGeuIAG')

Comment: Is the Pricebook2Id you are using is Standard Price Book Id?

Comment: No.  It is Custom pricebook.  Trying to add the product to this custom pricebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that we cannot set `UseStandardPrice=true` on insert.  On insert it has to be set to False first, along with mentioning `UnitPrice`.  Then later do an additional update to set the `UseStandardPrice=true`.

```
PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id='01sN00000002OTsIAM',
    IsActive=true, 
    Product2Id='01tN0000004JGeuIAG', 
    UseStandardPrice=false,
    UnitPrice = 0.70
    );

insert pbe;

pbe.UseStandardPrice = true;
update pbe;
```